# Is it correct to say: “ to better understand this concept we bring another example”?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences is correct:
A. To better understand this concept, we bring another example.

B. To understand better this concept, we bring another example.

C. To understand this concept better, we bring another example.

Comment: I would change *bring* to *give* in both examples, unless you've actually brought a physical object as another example. I'd be happy with either A or C then, although B could still be used, but maybe with another comma.

Comment: I prefer *[will / now]* ***provide*** to *bring*. The use of *bring* is awkward and unidiomatic.

Comment: You never put anything between the verb and its object. So that makes (b) bad. The others are both grammatical, but (a) is more complicated than (c), which would be the normal way to say it (except that one _gives_ examples in American English, instead of _bringing_ them).

Comment: Thank you so much Smock, Jason and John for your excellent comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from my misgiving about '*bring*' needing to be '*give*' both A and C are fine.

> A. To better understand this concept, we bring another example.
>   C. To understand this concept better, we bring another example.

B would need an extra comma:

> B. To understand better, this concept, we bring another example

'*this concept*' become a non-essential clause

> B. To understand better, we bring another example